# Criar uma Trigger com JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Boa tarde pessoal,

Eu tenho duas tabelas:

```
SELECT [CodigoProduto]
  ,[CodigoDistribuidor]
  ,[Produto]
  ,[ProdutoLimpo]
  ,[NomeMarca]
  ,[StatusProduto]
  ,[ChaveProduto]
  FROM [dbo].[Produto]
  GO


SELECT [CodigoMarca]
  ,[NomeMarca]
  ,[MarcaCorreta]
  ,[GrupoMarca]
  ,[CodigoInterno]
  FROM [dbo].[Marca]
  GO
```

E estou tentando montar uma Trigger para que quando o Produto da tabela produto é preenchido, ele vai juntar o ProdutoLimpo(de caracteres), com o CodigoMarca da tabela Marca. (NomeMarca são chave nas duas tabelas).

Segue o que eu montei:

```
CREATE TRIGGER KEY_PRODUTO
ON Produto
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
@Id int,
@Produto nvarchar(50),
@ProdutoLimpo nvarchar(50),
@CodMarca int

SELECT @Id = CodigoProduto, @produto = Produto, @ProdutoLimpo = ProdutoLimpo 
FROM INSERTED 
INNER JOIN Marca on @CodMarca = CodigoInterno

UPDATE Produto SET ChaveProduto = CONCAT(@ProdutoLimpo, '_', @CodMarca ) WHERE CodigoProduto = @Id

END
GO
```

Não da Erro, no código, mas não funciona a Trigger.

Onde eu deveria colocar o Join? Acredito que ele esteja errado.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu JOIN está incorreto.

O seu ON está interagindo com duas coluas da mesma tabela.

Tenta algo assim:

```
SELECT @Id = INS.CodigoProduto, @produto = INS.Produto, @ProdutoLimpo = INS.ProdutoLimpo, @idMarca = M.CodigoMarca FROM INSERTED INS
LEFT JOIN Marca M on INS.NomeMarca = M.NomeMarca
```

Não cheguei a rodar, mas a sintaxe correta do join seria essa.

Comment: Muito obrigado Pedro, com sua resposta, atualizei meu código e rodou.